# Where does one post questions like:

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

- What are good practices on file structure on websites?
- What are the best web hosts? Price and quality?
- What is the better, ASP.NET or PHP? What is easier to learn?
- Does displaying a copyright notice on its own protect you, or do you need to go through the government?

The more "open ended but generally standardized" ones?

There are many Stack Exchange sites and I am just wondering what one, if it exists, would be best. I have learned that Stack Overflow is not the place for this type of questions.

Comment: @Seth That's... not a good duplicate, Pachonk's example questions don't really fit anywhere on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Yannis - What was that website you've been floating around? The answer to SE not constructive?

Comment: @Oded [Slant.co](http://slant.co/) - They've build the entire site with recommendation questions in mind, great alternative to SE for NC questions.

Comment: @Yannis True enough..  Do you think another answer would be in place here or just a close since you don't think that's a good duplicate?

Comment: @Pachonk - These fall under our "not-constructive" close reason. They are polls. They are [shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) questions. Try http://slant.co/ for such questions.

Comment: @Oded, there are still questions slightly based upon opinion, yet there is probably a "common practice" of "What are good practices on file structure on websites?" and "Does displaying a Copywrite notice on its own protect you, or do you need to go through the goverment?" types.

Comment: Somewhere that isn't within the Stack Exchange network of sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My responses to these questions would tend to go along these lines:

- What are good practices on file structure on websites?

Migrate to Web masters

- What are the best web hosts? Price and quality?

Off-topic. We don't do web hosting referrals. You should do your own shopping research.

- What is the better, ASP.NET or PHP? What is easier to learn?

Not constructive. Asks for discussion and opinion, and needs much more information about the specific use to offer advice. Evaluate yourself, narrow down to specific questions between them, and we'll try and help. Which is easier to learn depends on the student's specific learning abilities and capabilities, and is unanswerable by us.

- Does displaying a copyright notice on its own protect you, or do you need to go through the government?

Off topic. This is a question you should be asking of an attorney that is familiar with the specific copyright laws in your jurisdiction. Free legal advice given by anonymous strangers on a public website is worth exactly what you're paying for it.

Comment: They were actually randomized questions that were somewhat similiar. What is Web Masters?

Comment: [WebMasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) is a site here at [se].

Answer (score 5):

The Stack Exchange network is excellent for questions which have a definitive answer that will be correct for a long period of time. Ask yourself if an answer you would receive is likely to be accurate a year from now, or 3? Unfortunately it's not the right place for subjective questions as they often result in a debate and a good answer now might be invalid in a few months time.

For questions like that, you should Google and find a forum/newsgroup dedicated to the topic in question.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything belongs on Stack Exchange. Subjective, open ended questions or shopping list questions are just not a good fit for a Q&A platform, which is unfortunately the platform underlying every SE site.

As Yannis has mentioned, sites like Slant.co are designed with opinion polls in mind. You'll have a much easier time getting a feel for public opinion there.

Your last question appears to be objective, but I'm not sure if there's an SE site yet that deals with legal issues. If your copyright question is specifically about software you are working on, it might be a good question for Programmers<sup>*</sup>.

EDIT:

* I stand corrected, [it is not a good question for Programmers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173888/where-does-one-post-questions-like/173890?noredirect=1#comment518585_173890). You could try looking if there's already a proposal regarding law or legal matters on Area51, although the answer to your question *is* highly dependent on what jurisdiction you are talking about.

Comment: I _believe_ legal questions have been shied away from as there are potential liability issues involved. I may be wrong and am happy to be corrected.

Comment: Re the last question: While software licensing is on topic on Programmers, questions that are _mostly_ about legal issues are not (we are programmers, not lawyers). The "do you need to go through the goverment" part reads too much as something that's dependent on local laws, thus off topic for Programmers. We can help explain what's the difference between various open source licenses (for example), but we can't really help when someone sues you (or give you advice on what to do to not get sued).